# Any way to 'fake' multiple series for single chart or same DateTime axis for multiple charts?

Tags: apache-flex, datetime, charts

I want a chart that has several separate series running in rows across. They are largely separate charts and should not overlap, but all share the same horizontal datetimeaxis.  They don't share the same y-axis, however and that's where I'm getting stuck.

I have tried having a linechart series and then a plotchart series, but it will only allow a single `<mx:series>` per chart without having them inside the same series which as far as I can tell will place the charts on top of each other in the z-axis. I can stack them and have them completely separate charts, but it was proving to be somewhat irritating having them align correctly.

Is there any reasonable way of combining multiple charts into one like this? Basically having rows in a table where each row is a different chart but the columns are consistent. or am I going to be best served just by stacking separate ones?

an illustration of what i'm going for is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Renf.png

Comment: Damon, I've commented your previous question. Do you need an example of parseFunction?

Comment: I got the multiple lines on one series working no prob (Except for flash builder's refusal to honour minimum and maximum on my datetimeaxis)  this is more looking for ways to accommodate multiple charts with many things in common. Like if I could have multiple <mx:Series> in one chart, rather than <mx:LineSeries> which I know you can. I will reword the question..

Comment: It's not entirely clear at what point you're having problems -- it's certainly possible to put multiple series on a chart: stick all the series in an array and assign it to the 'series' property on the chart object.  Can you tell us what you've tried already?

Comment: I have made charts with multiple series but they overlap each other on the z-axis. I want to know if it's possible to make a chart with multiple series that are on separate vertical rows. i edited the question a bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the only way to do this is to stack separate charts.  With a little care, it is possible to set things up so that the x-axes line up properly -- the project my team is working on has this.